# Some Win2D effects not working with Composition APIs (unsupported?)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, win2d

I'm working with some Win2D effects and the Composition APIs in a UWP application and I'm having some issues with some of the available effects.

Here's a working method I use to blur some content behind a target element:

```
public static SpriteVisual GetAttachedBlur<T>(
    [NotNull] this T element, float blur, int ms) where T : FrameworkElement
{
    // Get the visual and the compositor
    Visual visual = element.GetVisual();
    Compositor compositor = visual.Compositor;

    // Create the blur effect and the effect factory
    GaussianBlurEffect blurEffect = new GaussianBlurEffect
    {
        Name = "Blur",
        BlurAmount = blur,
        BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Hard,
        Optimization = EffectOptimization.Balanced,
        Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("source")
    };
    CompositionEffectFactory effectFactory = compositor.CreateEffectFactory(blurEffect);

    // Setup the rest of the effect
    CompositionEffectBrush effectBrush = effectFactory.CreateBrush();
    effectBrush.SetSourceParameter("source", compositor.CreateBackdropBrush());

    // Assign the effect to a brush and display it
    SpriteVisual sprite = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
    sprite.Brush = effectBrush;
    sprite.Size = new Vector2((float)element.ActualWidth, (float)element.ActualHeight);
    ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(element, sprite);
    return sprite;
}
```

Now, it works perfectly fine, but if I try to replace that `GaussianBlurEffect` effect with for example a `DirectionalBlurEffect`, I get an exception when I call the `CreateEffectFactory` method, saying that the input effect is not supported.

Now, I [looked at the documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/N_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Effects.htm) and it seems that both those effects have the `[NoComposition]` attribution, so my first question is:

> If both of the effects are unsupported (`[NoComposition]` attribute), why is it that the `GaussianBlurEffect` works fine and the `DirectionalBlurEffect` doesn't?

And the second question I have:

> Is there another way to use/apply that `DirectionalBlurEffect`? There are quite a few Win2D effects that are marked as `[NoComposition]` that I would like to use, is there a workaround for that or do I just have to give up on them?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think it unsupport

Comment: @lindexi Yeah, I've noticed the attribute too, did you even read the full question?

Comment: I mean I agree with you.

Comment: @lindexi Yup, looks like the official Win2D documentation wasn't updated for the latest releases of Windows 10, so some of the officially unsupported effects were in fact working fine (like the `GaussianBlurEffect`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Win2D documentation wasn't updated, and right now only the`GaussianBlurEffect` is supported (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/issues/218))